# How can I correctly add a shadow and a gradient to my triangular shape?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, linear-gradients

I want to make the following design:

[image: Sample image]

I tried with `:after` and `:before` but it does not work. Here’s my current code:

```css
.design {
  background: #ea053a;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 155px;
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 228px;
}

.design:before {
  border-top: 43px solid #ea053a;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 40px;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 128px;
}
```

```html
<div class="design"></div>
```

How could I leave it the same as the original design and with the following two properties?:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ea053a, #d0021b);
```

Comment: Just use a width of 0 for the `::before`. https://jsfiddle.net/z3yj1m0p/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an idea with skew transformation and `drop-shadow` filter. You simply need some extra element to correctly have the gradient. The trick is to invert the skew to keep the gradient direction correct *(not needed if we deal with solid color)*

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
}

.box span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box span:first-of-type {
  left: 0;
  transform: skewY(35deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.box span:last-of-type {
  right: 0;
  transform: skewY(-35deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.box span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, blue , red );
  transform-origin: inherit;
}

.box span:first-of-type::before {
  transform: skewY(-35deg);
}

.box span:last-of-type::before {
  transform: skewY(35deg);
}

p {
 margin:0;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:45px;
 line-height:100px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span><span></span>
  <p>29</p>
</div>
```

[image: CSS triangle linear gradient and shadow]

Here is how we can do with a left or right gradient. In this case we don't need extra elements because the skew will not affect the direction:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
}

.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,blue,red);
  background-size:200% 100%;
}

.box:before{
  left: 0;
  transform: skewY(35deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.box:after{
  right: 0;
  transform: skewY(-35deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  background-position:right;
}

p {
 margin:0;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:45px;
 line-height:100px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <p>29</p>
</div>
```

And here is with an arbitrary gradient:

```css
.box {
   --g:linear-gradient(45deg,blue,red 60%,yellow); /* gradient coloration*/

  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin:15px;
  display:inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
}

.box span {
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box span:first-of-type {
  left: 0;
  transform: skewY(35deg);
  transform-origin: top right;
}

.box span:last-of-type {
  right: 0;
  transform: skewY(-35deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
}

.box span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: var(--g);
  background-size:200% 100%;
  transform-origin: inherit;
}

.box span:first-of-type::before {
  transform: skewY(-35deg);
}

.box span:last-of-type::before {
  transform: skewY(35deg);
  background-position:right;
}

p {
 margin:0;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:45px;
 line-height:100px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span><span></span>
  <p>29</p>
</div>

<div class="box" style="--g:linear-gradient(-62deg,blue,red 60%,yellow)">
  <span></span><span></span>
  <p>29</p>
</div>
```

[image: CSS gradient and drop shadow]

Since each element is taking `50%` of the width we make the background to be `200%` to have its size as the main container then we adjust the position to create the illusion of one background. It's like each element will show half of the main background.

---

An optimized version using `mask`

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
}
.box > div {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(35deg, blue, red);
  -webkit-mask: conic-gradient(from -50deg at bottom,#000 100deg,#0000 0);
  
p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <p>29</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or `clip-path`

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
}
.box > div {
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(35deg, blue, red);
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 70%,50% 100%,0 70%);
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 45px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <p>29</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use clip-path as I did. Here is my solution.

```css
.design {
  background: #ea053a;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0 0);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0 0);
  height: 155px;
  width: 155px;
}

.month {
  text-align:center;
  padding: 1rem 0 .25rem 0;
  color:#fff;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.day {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="design">
  <div class="month">Diciembre</div>
  <div class="day">29</div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no shadow and no gradient

Answer (score 0):

If you change your CSS to the following minor changes, then you can achieve the result that you have expected:

```
.design {
  background: #ea053a;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
}

.design:before {
  border-top: 43px solid #ea053a;
  border-left: 90px solid transparent;
  border-right: 90px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 40px;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 0;
}
```

Here is the working of the above CSS:

```css
.design {
  background: #ea053a;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 180px;
}

.design:before {
  border-top: 43px solid #ea053a;
  border-left: 90px solid transparent;
  border-right: 90px solid transparent;
  margin-right: 40px;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="design">

</div>
```

Hope this was helpful.

[My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82591pwm/)

Answer (score -1):

Change to (only changed lines listed, keep everything else as-is):

```
.design:before {
  ...
  border-left: 114px solid transparent;
  border-right: 114px solid transparent;
  ...
  width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution to add shadow and gradient to the shape

```css
.design {
  background: #ea053a;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 155px;
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  position: relative;
  width: 228px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8));
 
}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  top: 155px;
  width: 228px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(49% 44%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(49% 44%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
  background-color: #ea053a;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  
}
```

```html
<div class="design">
  <div class="triangle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the shadow and the gradient?

Comment: can you please edit the post and update it in the answer, if it is possible, then it is a good solution