# How I Can Design With Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make the following design.
I used the HTML Graphics but not worked.
How can I make it with `css` and `html`?

---

[image]

Comment: Hello Heydari, what have you tried so far ? Have you looked here on Stack ? Show us your code and what is not working for you.

Comment: a good starting point : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54550358/8620333

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/the-shapes-of-css/#pointer

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/a4wsju97/](https://jsfiddle.net/a4wsju97/)

Comment: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/QoLJwq?editors=1100

Comment: This is another way you can do, it will provide you flexibility to place the block any where on the page rather than fixed positions. GIT: https://github.com/helloritesh000/how-i-can-design-with-css

Answer (score 1):

```css
.new_site_ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #C5BBD4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #C5BBD4, #FC9D96);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #C5BBD4, #FC9D96);
  background: linear-gradient(top left, #C5BBD4, #FC9D96);
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.new_site_ribbon:before {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(164, 157, 218, 0.65) rgba(164, 157, 218, 0.65) rgba(164, 157, 218, 0.65) transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
}

.new_site_ribbon:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid #fc9d96;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="new_site_ribbon">Take the tour!</div>
```